# __call method for class resolving

Tags: php, sdk, magic-methods

I'm  trying to develop an `SDK` library and use it with all microservices I have. So, in the package will be parent `Sdk` class and within it I would like to use `__call()` method to resolve classes that are responsible for certain purposes.

That's my solution:

```
public function __call($class, $parameters)
{
    $class = '\\Sdk\\' . ucfirst($class) . '(' . implode(', ', $parameters) . ')';
    return new $class;
}
```

But for some reasons not all of my resolvable classes are not in the `Sdk\` namespace. How to customize it?

Comment: That's the least of your problems, `$class = 'Sdk\\' . $class . '(' . $parameters . ')';` won't work.

Comment: Are they loaded?  What other namespaces would they be in?  Just the root \?

Comment: `Sdk\Calls`, `Sdk\Sms`, `Sdk\Something` etc